# Нужно сделать с простого сообщения, ембед

Tags: python, discord, бот, discord.py

Вот код, который нужно переделать в ембед, помогите пожалуйста, не могу понять как это делать, почему-то выводит ошибки, ну да ладно, надеюсь поможете, вот код:

```py
#Команда для бана
@bot.command()
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
async def ban(ctx, member: discord.Member, *, reason=None):
    if member.id == ctx.author.id:
        await ctx.reply("Вы не можете забанить самого себя!")
        return
    
    if member.top_role >= ctx.author.top_role:
        await ctx.reply(f"Вы не можете забанить участника, у которого роль выше чем у вас!")         
        return
```

и вот ещё:

```py
@ban.error
async def ban_error( ctx, error ):
    if isinstance (error, commands.MissingRequiredArgument):
        author = ctx.message.author
        await ctx.reply( f'{ author.mention }, обязятально укажите участника которого нужно забанить!' )
    if isinstance(error, commands.MissingPermissions):
        author = ctx.message.author
        await ctx.reply(f'{ author.mention }, у вас нет прав!')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#Команда для бана
@bot.command()
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
async def ban(ctx, member: discord.Member, *, reason=None):
    if member.id == ctx.author.id:
        await ctx.reply(embed=discord.Embed(description="Вы не можете забанить самого себя!"))
        return
    
    if member.top_role >= ctx.author.top_role:
        await ctx.reply(embed=discord.Embed(description=f"Вы не можете забанить участника, у которого роль выше чем у вас!"))         
        return
```

```
@ban.error
async def ban_error( ctx, error ):
    if isinstance (error, commands.MissingRequiredArgument):
        author = ctx.message.author
        await ctx.reply( embed=discord.Embed(description=f'{ author.mention }, обязятально укажите участника которого нужно забанить!' ))
    if isinstance(error, commands.MissingPermissions):
        author = ctx.message.author
        await ctx.reply(embed=discord.Embed(description=f'{ author.mention }, у вас нет прав!'))
```